# pdfTeX warning (dest): name{environment.1.1} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, cross-referencing, enumerate

I get a warning with this minimal code

> pdfTeX warning (dest): name{exercise.1.2} has been referenced but
>   does not exist, replaced by a fixed one

And the reference `\ref{a}` points to the wrong place (first page, when it should point to the second `\begin{exercise}`). The problem goes away if I remove the `{enumerate}` environment.

What's going on? How to fix it?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}[chapter]

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Filling the first page to show where the \verb|\ref{a}| points.

\chapter{chap}
\begin{exercise} \label{a}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Foo
  \end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}

Bar \ref{a}.

\end{document}
```

*Disclaimer*: This is a minimal example coming from a 200 pages document. If some answer solves this problem but the problem remains in the document, I will try to create a new minimal example (but right now I can't do anything, I'm shooting in the dark). I think that won't be necessary, but just so you know.

Comment: Any better title for the question is welcome (edit the question yourself), but right now I can't think of a more telling title.

Comment: Okey, the problem seems to be solved if I use `\leavevmode`  after `\label{..}`. But why? And how can I avoid the need for `\leavevmode` (which I don't want).

Comment: btw, you could replace the word ejercicio with something more ... *english* ;-)

Comment: I believe this has asked before.